# How to compare two polygons?

Tags: polygons

I have these polygon points which are like these:

```
a = {Polygon[{{1504.1, 456.266}, {1539.8, 402.781}, {1588.17, 
    378.487}, {1528.17, 456.266}}], 

b=  Polygon[{{273.801, 456.266}, {273.801, 306.852}, {545.027, 
    306.852}, {587.642, 456.266}}], 

c=  Polygon[{{1495.53, 456.266}, {1500.18, 386.794}, {1539.8, 
    402.781}, {1504.1, 456.266}}], 

d= Polygon[{{1528.17, 456.266}, {1588.17, 378.487}, {1636.98, 
    345.708}, {1648.84, 456.266}}], 

e= Polygon[{{1569.07, 306.852}, {1494.36, 368.012}, {1031.56, 
    341.018}, {1028.45, 306.852}}], 

f= Polygon[{{1032.95, 456.266}, {1031.56, 341.018}, {1494.36, 
    368.012}, {1500.18, 386.794}, {1495.53, 456.266}}], 

g= Polygon[{{1648.84, 456.266}, {1636.98, 345.708}, {1641.75, 
    306.852}, {2025.09, 306.852}, {2025.09, 456.266}}], 

h= Polygon[{{587.642, 456.266}, {545.027, 306.852}, {1028.45, 
    306.852}, {1031.56, 341.018}, {1032.95, 456.266}}], 

i= Polygon[{{1641.75, 306.852}, {1636.98, 345.708}, {1588.17, 
    378.487}, {1539.8, 402.781}, {1500.18, 386.794}, {1494.36, 
    368.012}, {1569.07, 306.852}}]}
```

Now, from here, I want to extract the common points of i from a to h. So, suppose, the first value of i {1641.75, 306.852} is common in g. So, I want to extract g and save it. Then the second value {1636.98, 345.708} is common in d. So, then I want to extract d and save it. In this way, I want to find all the polygons that have one point which is common with i.

Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's reformulate data a bit, you do not need all those variables and `Polygon`s:

```
plgs = {

   {{1504.1, 456.266}, {1539.8, 402.781}, {1588.17, 378.487}, {1528.17, 456.266}},

   {{273.801, 456.266}, {273.801, 306.852}, {545.027, 306.852}, {587.642, 456.266}},

   {{1495.53, 456.266}, {1500.18, 386.794}, {1539.8, 402.781}, {1504.1, 456.266}},

   {{1528.17, 456.266}, {1588.17, 378.487}, {1636.98, 345.708}, {1648.84, 456.266}},

   {{1569.07, 306.852}, {1494.36, 368.012}, {1031.56, 341.018}, {1028.45, 306.852}},

   {{1032.95, 456.266}, {1031.56, 341.018}, {1494.36, 368.012}, {1500.18, 386.794}, {1495.53, 
     456.266}},

   {{1648.84, 456.266}, {1636.98, 345.708}, {1641.75, 306.852}, {2025.09, 306.852}, {2025.09, 
     456.266}},

   {{587.642, 456.266}, {545.027, 306.852}, {1028.45, 306.852}, {1031.56, 341.018}, {1032.95, 
     456.266}},

   {{1641.75, 306.852}, {1636.98, 345.708}, {1588.17, 378.487}, {1539.8, 402.781}, {1500.18, 
     386.794}, {1494.36, 368.012}, {1569.07, 306.852}}};
```

Let's get the picture, where orange is i-th polygon:

```
Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@plgs[[;; -2]]}, 
{FaceForm[Orange], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@plgs[[-1]]}}]
```

[image]

Length of i-th:

```
iLength = Length[plgs[[-1]]]
```

> 7

Now compare the lengths:

```
neigh = Select[plgs[[;; -2]], 
Length[Union[Join[#, plgs[[-1]]]]] =!= Length[#] + iLength &];
```

and you got the neighbores:

```
Graphics[{{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@neigh}, 
{FaceForm[Orange], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@plgs[[-1]]}}]
```

[image]

This works only if polygons have exactly the same points. If they do not, you can `Round` your data so points do become equivalent. Or use Other function in `Select` based, for example, on some `EuclideanDistance` less than a threshold criteria.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But, the problem is I can't reform the data. The data I get has a polygon in front of it. How can I remove the polygon name from there?

Comment: @Odrisso `Cases[data, Polygon[x_] -> x, Infinity]`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perfectly works. :)

Comment: Can you please explain this line a bit further: I don;t understand the line: neigh = Select[plgs[[;; -2]], 
  Length[Union[Join[#, plgs[[-1]]]]] =!= Length[#] + iLength &]

Comment: @Odrisso please read docs carefully on every function there - especially `Union`. If 2 lists have the same point `Union` will remove duplicate and the total length of 2 lists will decreases. You could also use `DeleteDuplicates` instead of `Union`.